# Count unique values in range if matches found in set of criteria ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given many ranges containing text values, how would you count the unique values in one range if matches are found in a set of criteria ranges. So a **formula should return 4** in the example below:

[Count unique values in A3:A12 if matches found in B3:B12 or B17:B26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZExZq.png)

| count_unique_range | criteria_range_1 | criteria_range_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Srijeet | Lua | Mia |
| Jahaan | Atakan | Caroline |
| Bogdan | Atakan | Caroline |
| **Skanda** | Harrison | Annika |
| **Liam** | Carter | Skanda |
| Liam | Liam | Carter |
| **Francois** | Francois | Chelsea |
| Makayla | Francois | Daniella |
| Malakai | Jaswant | Sowmiya |
| **Sowmiya** | Abrielle | Sowmiya |

If this can be done with only `COUNTUNIQUEIFS()`, how would you set the criterion to match values in the count_unique_range with criteria_range1 or criteria_range2:

`COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A3:A12, B3:B12, [criterion1], B17:B26, [criterion2])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using COUNTUNIQUEIFS, you could try using COUNTUNIQUE but with the values filtered according to if they match or not your ranges.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A12,IFNA(XMATCH(A3:A12,{B3:B12;B17:26}),0)))
```

If you have more ranges add them inside the curly brackets with semicolons